# How to start user input on textfield from the middle of the screen?

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

The user input always start on leading. How can I align it exactly below the "Text" so that user starts the input in the middle of the screen?

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            VStack {
                Text("Math problem from database goes here.")
                TextField("User answer", text: $userAnswer).frame(alignment: .center)
            }.frame(width: 600, height: 100, alignment: .center)
        }.frame(width: 600, height: 200, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

This is what I get
[image: This is what I get]

Comment: Please do not post code as image, post it as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `multilineTextAlignment` function.

Here is the code to your `TextField` centered.

```
TextField("User answer", text: $userAnswer).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
```